# xslt to replace p tag with p tag with attributes

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have an xml file with many p tags --

INPUT --

```
        <p>
              <inline-img class="full">
                <web-main-photo>
                  <photo src="http://yahoo.com/test.jpg"/>
                </web-main-photo>
                <data>
                  <br/>
                  <caption>
                    <p> (Nick Wass/Associated Press)</p>
                  </caption>
                </data>
              </inline-img>
            </p>
            <p>this is content </p>
            <p>After missing the past three games with an injured left
leg, Martin Erat will return to the <a href="/blog/">Capitals</a>'
lineup Saturday night at Verizon Center against the Tampa Bay
Lightning.</p>
            <p>Erat, 31, suffered the injury on April 6 at Florida
when Panthers defenseman Erik Gudbranson delivered a late hit from
behind that sent the veteran winger awkwardly into the boards. He
avoided significant harm, though, and after five consecutive days of
skating Erat said he's prepared to get back to game action.</p>
        <p>
              <inline-img class="full">
                <web-main-photo>
                  <photo src="http://yahoo.com/test.jpg"/>
                </web-main-photo>
                <data>
                  <br/>
                  <caption>
                    <p> (Nick Wass/Associated Press)</p>
                  </caption>
                </data>
              </inline-img>
            </p>
            <p>"Feeling good. Feels better every day, I'm pretty much
ready to go," Erat said, adding that while he would have much rather
been playing games with his new team the time to take part in practice
and watch the system work from above should help him make a smooth
transition.</p>
```

INPUT ENDS HERE

I want all the p tags which are above inline img class to be replaced by  and it will look like

```
        <p channel="y.com">
          <inline-img class="full">
                <web-main-photo>
                  <photo src="http://yahoo.com/test.jpg"/>
                </web-main-photo>
                <data>
                  <br/>
                  <caption>
                    <p> (Nick Wass/Associated Press)</p>
                  </caption>
                </data>
              </inline-img>
            </p>
```

I dont want to replace any other normal p tags.So, in this particular example find and replace will happen at two places.I used this code,but it is not working.Please advise.Thanks.

XSLT CODE using xslt 1.0

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <xsl:template match="/">
            <component>

                    <p>
                        <xsl:call-template name="replace-text">
                                <xsl:with-param name="text"
select="/item/content" />
                                <xsl:with-param name="replace"
select="'&lt;p&gt;&lt;inline-img class='" />
                                <xsl:with-param name="by"
select="'&lt;p channel="y.com"&gt;&lt;inline-img class='" />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </p>

            </component>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="replace-text">
           <xsl:param name="text"/>
           <xsl:param name="replace" />
           <xsl:param name="by" />

           <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $replace)"/>
              <xsl:value-of select="$by" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
              <xsl:call-template name="replace-text">
                 <xsl:with-param name="text"
select="substring-after($text, $replace)"/>
                 <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
                 <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
              </xsl:call-template>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
           </xsl:otherwise>
           </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>

    Thanks so much for your help.I really appreciate it.
```

Comment: sorry,this forum cut my question.In short,I want to replace p tag if it comes above inline image class with  <p channel="y.com">

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p[*[1][self::inline-img]]">
  <p channel="y.com">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </p>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (the provided XML fragment wrapped into a single top element -- to be made into a well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
            <p>
                  <inline-img class="full">
                    <web-main-photo>
                      <photo src="http://yahoo.com/test.jpg"/>
                    </web-main-photo>
                    <data>
                      <br/>
                      <caption>
                        <p> (Nick Wass/Associated Press)</p>
                      </caption>
                    </data>
                  </inline-img>
                </p>
                <p>this is content </p>
                <p>After missing the past three games with an injured left
    leg, Martin Erat will return to the <a href="/blog/">Capitals</a>'
    lineup Saturday night at Verizon Center against the Tampa Bay
    Lightning.</p>
                <p>Erat, 31, suffered the injury on April 6 at Florida
    when Panthers defenseman Erik Gudbranson delivered a late hit from
    behind that sent the veteran winger awkwardly into the boards. He
    avoided significant harm, though, and after five consecutive days of
    skating Erat said he's prepared to get back to game action.</p>
            <p>
                  <inline-img class="full">
                    <web-main-photo>
                      <photo src="http://yahoo.com/test.jpg"/>
                    </web-main-photo>
                    <data>
                      <br/>
                      <caption>
                        <p> (Nick Wass/Associated Press)</p>
                      </caption>
                    </data>
                  </inline-img>
                </p>
                <p>"Feeling good. Feels better every day, I'm pretty much
    ready to go," Erat said, adding that while he would have much rather
    been playing games with his new team the time to take part in practice
    and watch the system work from above should help him make a smooth
    transition.</p>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<t>
   <p channel="y.com">
      <inline-img class="full">
         <web-main-photo>
            <photo src="http://yahoo.com/test.jpg"/>
         </web-main-photo>
         <data>
            <br/>
            <caption>
               <p> (Nick Wass/Associated Press)</p>
            </caption>
         </data>
      </inline-img>
   </p>
   <p>this is content </p>
   <p>After missing the past three games with an injured left
    leg, Martin Erat will return to the <a href="/blog/">Capitals</a>'
    lineup Saturday night at Verizon Center against the Tampa Bay
    Lightning.</p>
   <p>Erat, 31, suffered the injury on April 6 at Florida
    when Panthers defenseman Erik Gudbranson delivered a late hit from
    behind that sent the veteran winger awkwardly into the boards. He
    avoided significant harm, though, and after five consecutive days of
    skating Erat said he's prepared to get back to game action.</p>
   <p channel="y.com">
      <inline-img class="full">
         <web-main-photo>
            <photo src="http://yahoo.com/test.jpg"/>
         </web-main-photo>
         <data>
            <br/>
            <caption>
               <p> (Nick Wass/Associated Press)</p>
            </caption>
         </data>
      </inline-img>
   </p>
   <p>"Feeling good. Feels better every day, I'm pretty much
    ready to go," Erat said, adding that while he would have much rather
    been playing games with his new team the time to take part in practice
    and watch the system work from above should help him make a smooth
    transition.</p>
</t>
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre, works like a magic.Right now,we are applying this to the top level element(element t in this case) or the entire xml.What if the element t is part of a bigger xml? like <item><a>content</a><b>content</b><t>the content above</t></item> and we want to apply it on t.What will change.I am working on it myself.if you have some time could you please post a solution so that i can check .Thanks again.

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <tag>
   <xsl:for-each select="//XPATH">

    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </tag>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p[*[1][self::inline-img]]">
  <p channel="y.com">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </p>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>